# How to force a list to be vertical using html css

Tags: html, css

I have a list i want to add to a `<div>`. Each listitem contains a `<div>` which in turn contain an image and a text string. The list must be vertical. I ve tried putting `display:block` for the `<ul>`  with `width:100%` but the list is flowing left to right horizontally. How do I make the list vertical?

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try putting `display: block` in the `<li>` tags instead of the `<ul>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is now a vertical list but the alignment is to the left. I want it to be at the centre

Comment: (This is an old question, I know) There are two scenarios here: 1) if you want the _text alignment_ to be center, then use `text-align: center` on the `ul`; but if you want the list itself to be centered on the screen with the text still left aligned, then define a `width` or `max-width` property and add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to it.

Answer (score 23):

I would add this to the LI's CSS

```
.list-item
{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: I have to remove the clear:left; and it works calm,any idea why ?

Answer (score 10):

Hope this is your structure:

```
   <ul> 
     <li>
        <div ><img.. /><p>text</p></div>
    </li>
     <li>
        <div ><img.. /><p>text</p></div>
    </li>
     <li>
        <div ><img.. /><p>text</p></div>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

By default, it will be add one after another row:

```
-----
-----
-----
```

if you want to make it vertical, just add float left to li, give width and height, make sure that content will not break the width:

```
|  |  |
|  |  |

li
{
   display:block;
   float:left;
   width:300px; /* adjust */
   height:150px; /* adjust */
   padding: 5px; /*adjust*/
}
```

Answer (score 7):

CSS

```
li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Works for me also.