# Drop down menu is misaligned, why?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to create a drop down menu navigation where the drop down content is revealed after hovering over the navigation button.

Unfortunately, the drop down list end up vertical with odd sizing.

Could you please explain to me what I've done wrong and how the resolution works?

JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/bttjb72x/

```
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav ul li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(25, 255, 25, 1);
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0
}
#nav ul ul li {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#nav ul ul a {
  padding: 10px 15px
}
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">End</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Browse</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Browse</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">End</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Browse</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">End</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Where is your css

Comment: I see. Would class be the better option?

Comment: For the vertical issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703228/how-to-force-a-list-to-be-vertical-using-html-css

Comment: I did a display block in the li tags and it doesn't work. It looks like my ul or nav is restricted and thus maybe the drop down list is beneath it. Not sure.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bttjb72x/

Comment: what do you mean by " vertical with odd sizing" can you please specify what are you attempting to get?